# How to use authorization API in ng-admin app?

Tags: ng-admin

I've been thinking to use multiple APIs in my ng-admin app. I also have an another authorization API running on the host which provide tokens for other API calls.

I would like to use all above APIs in my ng-admin app.
[Customizing the API Mapping of the ng-admin documentation](http://ng-admin-book.marmelab.com/doc/API-mapping.html) describes below code to authorize APIs

```
myApp.config(['RestangularProvider', function(RestangularProvider) {
var login = 'admin',
    password = '53cr3t',
    token = window.btoa(login + ':' + password);
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token}); }]);
```

However, where is the place to specify my authorization api url here?
How to config auth API to provide tokens to all other APIs?
On the other hand, what I have to do for refresh tokens?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should setup Restangular interceptors based on the url. But I recommend that you ask your question with the Restangular tag, because ng-admin does nothing special here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ng-admin-book.marmelab.com/doc/Custom-pages.html

go through the documentation of ng-admin and see how to add custom pages in ng-admin. I have used authorisation api in my code as follows:

```
if(localStorage.getItem('yourTokenKey') !== null && localStorage.getItem("yourTokenKey") != 'undefined')
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");
    else
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");

$stateProvider
    .state('login',{            
        url:'/login',
        templateUrl:'templates/login.html',
        controller:'loginController'
    })
    .state('stats', {
        parent: 'main',
        url: '/stats',
        templateUrl: 'templates/inventoryFormTemplate.html'         
    })
    .state('dashboard2', {
        parent: 'main',
        url: '/dashboard'           
    })
    .state('inventoryItem', {
        parent: 'main',
        url: '/inventoryItem'           
    })
    .state('requestInventoryItem', {
        parent: 'main',
        url: '/requestInventoryItem'            
    })
    .state('logout', {          
        url: '/logout',
        controller:'logoutController'           
    });
```