# Login with Api which return token in ng-admin

Tags: ng-admin

I have RestApi which has

(Post Request with username and password)http://localhost:8000/authenticate

and (This will check the token is valid or not)http://localhost:8000/authorize

So i want to add this login in marmelab/ng-admin angular js plugin

If someone has done please share the code...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do not treat stackoverflow as a code writing service. Please go through the how to ask section and improve or remove your question.

Comment: What have you done so far? Post your code. What is not working? What is unclear? Did you google this? You can't be the first person who needs a REST API with authentication and authorization features.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987892/how-to-use-authorization-api-in-ng-admin-app/39425081#39425081 go through the above link may be it will help you.